# Difference between ISupportInitialize (BeginInit/EndInit) and SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout

Tags: .net, winforms, system.componentmodel

Could someone please explain what the difference is between using the ISupportInitialize interface methods (BeginInit/EndInit) and using SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout?

Is ISupportInitialize ONLY used during construction/"initial" initialization... or can it be used later when you want to add new child controls to an existing parent control?

Any particular differences?

I greatly appreciate your help!

Thank you,

Pato

Comment: ---------------
Today I want to implement dynamic control creation by converting it from designer code. Which one take precedence? BeginInit() or SuspendLayout()?

----------------------                ((ISupportInitialize)Process_GroupControl).BeginInit();
Process_GroupControl.SuspendLayout();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The interface ISupportInitialize lives in the System.dll and is just a fairly generic concept in the realm of Components. Incidentally, many parts of System.Windows.Forms are Components, and also Windows.Forms is the main user of the ComponentModel stuff.

Suspend/ResumeLayout is a pure Windows.Forms thing and really telling a control to not try and do graphics while you are e.g. adding child controls or changing properties.

Answer (score -1):

Correct used code in VB.Net for this, most decompilers get this wrong.

```
CType(Me.pictureBox1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
```